# Android web interaction

Tags: java, android

I am doing a project on android for file and media backup on a remote server. However I am stuck with the connection methods I should be implementing. My question is how to implement the connection and properly send the data to the server?

Comment: My answer below might not be the most specific - but your question is a little unclear. Add some more information and I would be glad to update my answer with some more specific information.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.......... well what m trying to do is select a bunch of mp3 or say messeges from phone to the server cloud. So m confused what to do for this. I request you to kindly address this too.  And again I have been reading about Json in android, still not so clear about it. Hope you could help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you asking, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on what kind of server/receiving application you're uploading to.

If you want HTTP file uploads, I highly recommend [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).

Otherwise, I you probably want some sort of asynchronous socket connection library, like [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty).

Comment: thank you so much for responding.......... well what m trying to do is select a bunch of mp3 or say messeges from phone to the server cloud.